# Configuring clock peripherals seems to ignore half of my configuration bits.

Tags: stm32

I'm configuring the RCC to activate clock for peripherals. However, when I use the SFRs to check registers, it doesn't match what I programmed.

```
RCC->AHBENR = (uint32_t) 0x000C0004;
```

When I check the AHBENR,the value is

```
0x14
```

I previously had only 0x00000014, so I am not sure if I'm compiling a previous build or why is half of my code being ignored?

In pseudo code, here is what the RCC does. It runs only once:

```
//Initialises HSE, CSS, HSI

//wait until HSE is ready

//Configure PLL to choose SYSCLK, fix the multiplicator at chosen value

//Fix PREDIV

//Activate PLL

**//Configure clock for peripherals. <- problem here.**
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using the STM32F0xx microchip. Thank for for help.

Comment: Download CubeMx for STM32F0. It has a clock generation tool which will give you all the prescalers in a diagram so you can see how it works. It will even generate the code for you if you want!

Comment: Thanks, I will use that to verify if I did the right things!